# PHP OpenID Library that allows facebook / openid / twitter, etc;

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, authentication, openid

I am looking for an already completed openid login library that I can just 'plug' into my application and allow for access using any of the openid, facebook, twitter, methods that you would see on many well accessible websites.

An example would be Woot.com's login:

https://account.woot.com/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fwoot.com%2fdefault.aspx

I would like one that I don't have to spend lots of time on, as I would like this accessibility for my users but I do not wish to sacrifice a large portion of my development tinkering with it, or working out bugs with facebook working, and not twitter, etc;

Thoughts?

Comment: After my findings, I have created an installation guide for a3m, the full details can be found here: http://blog.biernacki.ca/2010/11/a3m-a-codeigniter-account-authentication-authorization-module-installation/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

HybridAuth, a free and open source web-based PHP Social Networking service project enables users to authenticate in your blog, Web site or application using their OpenID, Twitter, Facebook, MySpaceID, Google, AOL, Friendster or Vimeo Accounts.

HybridAuth is one and simple SSO PHP Library.

http://www.phpkode.com/projects/item/hybridauth/

Answer (score 5):

I actually searched some more and found that there is a CodeIgniter module that does all this (back in February/March when I was working hard on my app, there was none).

For people that need this as well for CodeIgniter:
http://code.google.com/p/a3m/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few open source projects that are active on github and google code.

http://github.com/openid/php-openid

But that is as simple as it gets unless you are already using a created framework like Kohana or Cake or whatever.  IF you are using one of those, chances are they have worked on a module for OAuth and FB / TW / OID stuff.  I prefer Kohana, and they have many great modules.

Comment: This a open-id only solution, which is precisely not what he is looking for. Also that particular library is mostly abandoned.