# PHP Login with Facebook, Twitter etc

Tags: php, openid

I want my users to be able to login to my page at least via Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo and OpenID.
Is there already something out there which does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.janrain.com/
http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/get-janrain-engage

Comment: I'm looking for an easy to implement way. Therefore janrain looks like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Is not what you are looking for, but with OpenInviter, you can know if the user insert a valid login username / password

Answer (score 0):

A google search of OpenID API and Facebook Login API should cover two of those, though i dont know how well they will all interact with eachother

[PHP OpenID Library that allows facebook / openid / twitter, etc;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237262/php-openid-library-that-allows-facebook-openid-twitter-etc)

Does that help?

Comment: wasn't me.
I actually upvoted it again so you get at least 0.